# save value though the activity is closed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Now I want to save the value(which is changed due to the clicks) even closing the activity.

The score increases and decreases whenever I click the button

But I want to save the value after I close this activity and reopen it
Some one said to use 
 SharedPreferences method, but I don't know how to apply it on my methods.

Please help me

```
public class MouseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    int score ;
    TextView Value,speed;
    ImageButton Plus, Minus;
    String msg = "10";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mouseactivity);

        Plus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.RClick);
        Minus = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.LClick);

        Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        speed.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/beb.otf"));
        Plus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        Minus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


        //왼 클릭 버튼 생성 및 이벤트 연결

       }
    @Override


public void onClick(View v)
{

    boolean showText = false;


if(v.getId()==R.id.RClick)
{


    if(score>=20)
    {score=20;

    String msg = "";
    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

    }
    else{
        score ++;
        String msg = "aa";
    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
    }
    }
else if (v.getId()==R.id.LClick)
{

            if(score<=0)
            {
            score=0;
            String msg = "";
            Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
            }
            else{
                score --;
                String msg = "bb";
                Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
            }
    }
else
{
    String msg = "";
    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

}

Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Save like this:

```
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

  ...

  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("yourKey", yourValue);
```

Read like this

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  int value = settings.getInt("yourKey", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your value on the **onPause** method of activity and retrieve it on the **onStart** or **onResume** method. You can do this because onPause is always called before exiting an activity.
Sample code to get the score in onResume:

```
SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(
                "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String score= preference.getString(
                "score", "0");//score is 0 by default
```

To save an entry on onPause method:

```
SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(
                "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                editor.putString("score",
                        score+"");
                editor.commit();
```

Comment: public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(
                "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                editor.putString("score",
                        score+"");
                editor.commit();
  
 }
public void onResume(){SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences(
        "mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String score= preference.getString(
        "score", "0");
 
}

Comment: I put your code like this, but th eapplication doesn't work T_T

Comment: The value still return 0 when I close the activity

Comment: @user3769541 you have @ override annotation right. something like @ Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);